# Node app route is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im fairly new to node JS and I've created the following 3 files and when save the application I got error

```
http.createServer(app).listen(**app.get('port')**, function(){
```

*the error is undefined is not a function*
I use nodemon and I see the error in the terminal

I want to keep the structure of the files(to initiate the server from different file - server.js )since I want to use TDD .

this is the files

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');

app = require('./app');
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

***app.js***

```
module.exports = function() {
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express();

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.use(require('./controllers/requests'));
    return app;

}
```

**requests.js**

```
var routers = require('express')
    , router = express.Router()

router.get('/wild', function(req, res) {
    debugger;
    res.send('Wolf, Fox, Eagle')
})

module.exports = router
```

**UPDATE**
**This is the update in the code** 
**app.js**

```
  module.exports = function() {
        var express = require('express'),
            app = express();

        app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
        app.use(function(){
            var routes = require('./controllers/requests') (app);
        });
        return app;

    }
```

**requests.js**
**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    var express = require('express')
        , router = express.Router();
    app.get('/wild', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Wolf, Fox, Eagle');
    })
}
```

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');

app = require('./app');
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});**
```

Comment: Your `requests.js` is invalid - you're using undefined `express`  variable. Please, verify that you copied your code correctly.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny-Thanks I have changed the typo but still I got the same error...any other idea?

Comment: I don't know which typo you changed, but right now `requests.js` is a mess. First, you load express and assign it to `routers` variable. Then, you're using undefined `express` variable to define another `router` variable. Then you call `.get` on `routers`, which is actually an express, not a Router. Finally, you're exporting `routers`. You `router` variable remains unused.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny-Thanks I've also changed the routers.get to router.get which I think the right way but still the same error is occurred ....

Comment: Your `requests.js` is still a total mess. You should definitely use some linter to statically analyse your code for errors.

Comment: It'll be very useful to see an error you're getting.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny- does the linter help in debug?if yes how should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invoke the function returned by module containing app.

```
app = require('./app') ();
```

Moreover, in **request.js** file you should define routes on your app instance:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
   app.get('/wild', function(req, res) {
      res.send('Wolf, Fox, Eagle');
   })
}
```

And in **app.js**:
app.use(function () {}) is used to define middlewares. Here you could call

```
var routes = require('./controllers/requests') (app);
```

**EDIT**

Please find here below the recap to answer your comments:

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./app') ();
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(err){
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**app.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
   var express = require('express'),
      app = express();

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    require('./controllers/requests')(app);
    return app;
}
```

**requests.js**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
   app.get('/wild', function(req, res) {
      res.send('Wolf, Fox, Eagle')
 });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks andre,where should I put the app = require('./app') (); ?

Comment: Can you please provide the full code in the replay (my posted code is very short...) since it is little bit confusing.

Comment: can you please assist ?

Comment: ive update the post with your comments,and still I get the error,do I miss something?